# Warning: Font shape LGR/mdbch/m/n undefined(Font) using LGR/cmr/m/n instead

Tags: fonts, warnings, font-encodings

Basically I get the warning:

```
Warning: Font shape LGR/mdbch/m/n undefined(Font) using LGR/cmr/m/n instead
```

in a paragraph with

```
\textdelta
```

This latter command has an orange background, color that points to an unrecognized command.

[image]

I know that this is just a warning, bud it would be to know if this would be worth to be solved. If so, how can I solve it?

I use TeXstudio and all the completion files have been activated (Options -> Configure TeXstudio -> Completion).

I forgot to mention that I am using these packages:

```
\usepackage[bitstream-charter]{mathdesign}
\usepackage{textgreek}                          % greek letters in text
```

Thanks in advance for any hints,

Comment: Are you sure that BitStream Charter has text Greek letters?

Comment: @Bernard I am not sure, but I think so, this is the font type I am using `\usepackage[bitstream-charter]{mathdesign}`

Comment: if this font type doesn't allow the use of Greek letters, my only solution would be the math package?

Comment: MathDesign's Charter has no support for Greek. If you just need some Greek letters, a substitute font can be found. Please, add a minimal example of code where you need Greek.

Comment: I checked no commercial (bisteam or ITC) charter font has greek nor cyrillic glyphs. That said, the `xcharter` doc says Linux Libertine could be used form math Greek (perhaps with some scaling). But Linux Libertine does have text Greek fonts, so you could try to use it for Greek text. I must say it should be easier to do with ` fontspec` and `Xe/LuaLaTeX`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error message means that the symbol you asked for is not in any of the fonts you selected, so the glyph is being taken from Computer Modern (`cmr`) instead.

The `textgreek` package is conflicting with `mathdesign`.

The `mathdesign` package substitutes glyphs from alternate fonts for most of the default LaTeX math-mode commands. When you select `\usepackage[charter]{mathdesign}` the package pulls the normal text-mode glyphs from the Charter font and the math-mode glyphs from various other sources.

The `textgreek` package, on the other hand, is providing Greek characters (in Greek encoding) in text mode instead of math mode. By default it uses the Computer Modern Greek font.

So `mathdesign` gives you Charter and alternate math fonts, but the `\textgreek` command asks the `textgreek` package to give you a Greek font from Computer Modern. If you only need the occasional Greek symbol as part of scientific writing (as it appears from the screenshot), then the `textgreek` package is not necessary.

Without knowing more about your setup (a MWE would be necessary), I would suggest using `$\delta$` or `$\Delta$`. Mathdesign also provides `$\deltaup$` and `$\Deltaup$` if you don't want the symbols slanted.

Comment: Thanks Andrew for your answer. I tried before $\delta$ but I didn't like the output, so I will use just \textdelta, it gives the symbol I want (ie. the shape) and it appears in the PDF, which is enough. I will just ignore the warning :)